# what's the Bitwise Tunnnlier equivalent for Linux?

Tags: linux, ssh

i used Tunnlier in windows, and it was perfect. after migrating to Linux i can't find anything like that to manage my SSH connections to use Terminal and SFTP and also save my connections to load later.

what do you recommend?

**PS:** moved to [ubuntu stackexchange](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3315/whats-the-bitwise-tunnnlier-equivalent-for-ubuntu)

Comment: I recommend editing `~/.ssh/config` and using keys. But that's not what you're looking for.